# How can I save bulk images with type django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: python-3.x, django, image

I am upload Images from Postman, and receiving them as type `django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile` but am getting an error.

Below is my View in Django :

```
class LiveImageBulkUploadView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = LiveImages.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LiveImagesSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # get the relevant event based on the uuid in the URL
        # TODO Finish this uploading part, it should be bulk upload.
        event_uuid = kwargs.get('event_uuid')
        event = get_object_or_404(Events, uuid=event_uuid)

        live_images_list = []

        for image in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
            # Open the image using PIL
            print(' image ', type(image))
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(image.read()))
            live_images_list.append(
                LiveImages(image=img, caption='', event=event))

        LiveImages.objects.bulk_create(live_images_list)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

My models are here :

```
class Events(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    """Events model"""

    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, max_length=500,
                            default=uuid.uuid4,
                            editable=False,
                            db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100, blank=False,
                            null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), upload_to='event_images', null=True,
                              max_length=900, blank=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(_('Is public'), default=True)
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(
        EventTypes, max_length=25, related_name='events_types',
        null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    views_count = models.BigIntegerField(_('Views count'), default=0)

    # TODO: Add an attribute is_live.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def increment_views(self):
        Events.objects.filter(
            pk=self.pk).update(views_count=F('views_count') + 1)


class LiveImages(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):

    """LiveImages model."""

    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, max_length=500,
                            default=uuid.uuid4,
                            editable=False,
                            db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)
    caption = models.CharField(
        _('Caption'), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), upload_to='live_images', null=True,
                              max_length=900, blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        Events, max_length=50,
        related_name='event_live_images', null=True,
        blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

Am getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/events/views.py", line 88, in post
    LiveImages.objects.bulk_create(live_images_list)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 816, in bulk_create
    returned_columns = self._batched_insert(
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1817, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1791, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1659, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1583, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1584, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1585, in <listcomp>
    self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj))
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1533, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 314, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:
  File "/home/idris/Documents/workspace/pixsar-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 529, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _committed
[21/Apr/2023 20:01:26] "POST /api/v1/events/5e578281-6426-4c1d-a68b-8a2e773e6b57/live-images/bulk-upload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 151590
```

How can I solve this ?